# Remember me function causes unknown error

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to make Laravel's "remember me" feature. The problem is that, whenever I create a `remember_token` column, I am unable to log in or register a user, as it gives some unknown error that I cannot find in any way. Also, I have no idea how to apply this functionality with my code.

Login and Registration Form (except that the registration form does not have a checkbox):

```
<form class="login-form needs-validation" method="POST" action="{{ route('loja.logar') }}" novalidate>
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" class="custom-control-input" id="remember">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="remember">Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

I'm not using Model, just a controller that is the SiteController:

```
public function logar(Request $req)
  {

    $data     = $req->all();
    $user     = Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']]);
    $this->validate($req, [
      'email' => ['required', 'email'],
      'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($user) {
      return redirect()->route('loja.index');
    } else {
      return redirect()->route('loja.login')
        ->with('status-verification', 'Error. Try again!');
    }
  }

 public function regist(Request $req)
  {
    $data      = $req->all();
    $validator = $this->validate($req, [
      'email' => [
        'required',
        'email',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
          if (Users::whereEmail($value)->count() > 0) {
            echo 1;
          }
        },
      ]
    ]);

    if ($validator) {
      Users::create([
        'email' =>               $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
      ]);
      return redirect()->route('loja.register');
    }
  }
```

User Table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
            $table->string('email', 191)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
        });
    }
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: an unknown error .. then how do you know there is an error at all?  and why are you writing your own login/register functionality?  you are also not passing the argument to `attempt` for the remember functionality and you need that column on the `users` table  ... the docs specifically tell you how to handle this functionality, with code examples

Comment: My question is how can I apply this functionality, if it is in the Attempt of the `public function logar()` . In addition, I know the error because when I create a `remember_token` column, I can't log in and it returns the incorrect login or password modal.

Comment: how did you create this column? ... we can figure this out, one step at a time :)

Comment: As mentioned on the documentation you should pass a boolean value as the second argument to the `attempt` method, and also your `users` table must have `remember_token` column. Documentation link [Remembering Users](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#remembering-users)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, guys. The `remember_token` column I created as varchar, 100 characters allowed. But whenever I created this column, login validation didn't work. My question is, how can I apply 'remember me' in this code. Should I just add the Boolean value to Attempt?

Comment: yes, you just pass the second argument to `attempt`, but you will need the `remember_token` column on the table ... that is how it matches the remember me cookie to the user

Comment: I thought I should do it another way, as I don't want the user to save the password if he doesn't check or check the checkbox.

Comment: When the user logs in, I don't want them to save the password if they don't check the checkbox.

Comment: remind the user, I meant.

Comment: Now I have changed two lines of code:

     `$ remember = $ req-> input ('remember');`
     `$ user = Auth :: attempt (['email' => $ data ['email'], 'password' => $ data ['password']], $ remember);`

But whenever I try to login with an account, the incorrect email or password modal is returning. It is probably some error with the column.

Comment: did you make the field `nullable` when you created it? i would just be looking at the responses from the server directly; perhaps the frontside is catching any error responses, if there is javascript involved

Comment: yes, I set it to null: `$ table->string('remember_token', 100)->nullable();`
The users table is being used in the registration function too, so when I register a user, `remember_token` is created as null.

Comment: An error is now appearing after I submit the form: The remember field must be true or false.

Comment: try using `$request->has('remember')` not the value of the input, you just want to know if it is passed at all, checked

Comment: Now the login is working perfectly. The problem is that when I log out, it does not remember the password.

Comment: I'm putting `$this->validate` the following:
`'remember' => 'boolean'`. The problem is that it returns the error mentioned above and if I remove it, everything works correctly, but it doesn't remember the password.

Comment: checkboxes are only submitted when they are checked and if you dont set a value they will have the value of 'on' ... and nothing is "remembering" any password

Comment: will it work if I put `value="false"` or `value="0"` ?

Comment: Ok. I put `value="0"` and the login was successful, but when the password was not remembered.